# How to select randomly from tables having one to many relationship?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have `Questions` table:

```
ID      TEXT             DISCIPLINE_ID
1   What is stack?            1
2   The biggest ocean is      1
```

And I have `Option` table that contains all of options to some question:

```
ID            TEXT                     IS_CORRECT   QUESTION_ID 
1       It is data structure             TRUE           1 
2          It is game                    FALSE          1 
3          I don't know                  FALSE          1
4          Atlantic                      FALSE          2
5          Pacific                       TRUE           2
6          Indian                        FALSE          2
```

I should select random 15 questions by discipline and all of options. Here is my try:

```
  SELECT Q.ID, Q.TEXT, O.ID, O.TEXT, O.IS_CORRECT 
    FROM (
          SELECT ID, TEXT 
             FROM QUESTION 
          WHERE DISCIPLINE_ID = 1 
             ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 15
         ) Q 
       JOIN OPTION O ON O.QUESTION_ID = Q.ID;
```

I selected all random 15 questions of the discipline. And then, I joined them with options. But it does not work. Because, I have 3 options for each question and I should get exactly 45 (3*15) rows from above query. But I get sometimes 30 rows, sometimes 33 rows. In other words, my query does not work correctly. Where is my mistake?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query, and note that 3 random results requires a smaller sample data set

Comment: @neo . . . Your query is fine.  Either you are miscounting the results, some questions do not have three options (or are missing from the options table), or some disciplines have fewer than 15 questions.

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be in data itself. If you have **less then 15 Qs** in some discipline then you'll get less then 45 records for this DISCIPLINE_ID. first check your data.